# Python Create Dictionary with Shapely Points from Linestring coordinates

Tags: python, point, geopandas, shapely, linestring

I have a Geodataframe with `Linestring Z geometries` as follows:

| id_line | geometry |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LINESTRING Z (0 0 0, 5 6 9, 1 2 3, ...) |
| 2 | LINESTRING Z (7 8 9, 9 8 7, 1 2 5, ...) |

each of the Linestring is made up of *n* triples of x, y, z coordinates.
What I am looking for? Extract each of the triples that make up each line and convert it into Shapely POINT, then save each of these points in a dictionary like that:

```
{id_line : [points]}
points_by_line = {1 : [POINT Z(0,0,0), POINT Z(5,6,9), POINT Z(1,2,3)], 2 : [POINT Z(7,8,9), POINT Z(9,8,7), POINT Z(1,2,5)]
```

How am I trying to do this?

```
#Extracting the geometries from the Geodataframe
lines_segments = real_traj['geometry']
# saving the coordinates in a list
line_coords = []
for line in lines_segments:
    coords_line = list(line.coords)
    line_coords.append(coords_line)
```

Then I am trying to create a function that will extract each of the coordinates and convert them into Shapely Points, but here is where I am stuck

```
def linestring_to_points(line_coords):
    # creating a list for stock the points of each line
    line_points = []
    for coords in line_coords:
        for point_coord in coords:
            # access accessing the coordinates of each point on the line and creating a point from 
            # each group of coordinates
            line_points.append(geometry.Point(point_coord))
    return {id_line:Point.coords}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to append the values to an existing key to a dictionary:

```
def append_point(dict_points, key, point):
    # Check if key exist in dict_points or not
    if key in dict_points:
        # Key exist in dict_points.
        # Check if type of point of key is list or not
        if not isinstance(dict_points[key], list):
            # If type is not list then make it list
            dict_points[key] = [dict_points[key]]
        # Append the point in list
        dict_points[key].append(point)
    else:
        # As key is not in dict_points,
        # so, add key-point pair
        dict_points[key] = point
```

Use the function in a for loop that will convert the coordinates of the linestrings into Shapely points:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("lines.shp")

points = {}
for i,line in enumerate(gdf.geometry):
    for coord in line.coords:
        point = Point(coord)
        append_point(points, gdf.iloc[i].id_line, point)
```

Output:

```
{1: [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c65c160>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c65cca0>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c65c640>],
2: [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x18598675400>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c69f460>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c69f3d0>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c69f4c0>],
3: [<shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x18598675400>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c69f460>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c69f3d0>,
  <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x1859c69f4c0>]}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the question is only *Create Shapely Points from Linestring coordinates* then the answer is:

```
print(line.wkt)
LINESTRING (22.6211173184358 -366.5480446927374, 21.05843575418999 -333.7317318435754, 21.57932960893859 -303.5198882681564, 21.57932960893859 -273.828938547486, 20.53754189944139 -236.8454748603352, 19.49575418994418 -206.1127374301676, 23.66290502793301 -172.775530726257, 25.74648044692742 -138.3965363128492, 27.30916201117323 -107.6637988826815, 25.22558659217881 -76.41016759776535, 27.30916201117323 -44.63564245810054)
for coord in list(line.coords):
    print(Point(coord))
POINT (22.6211173184358 -366.5480446927374)
POINT (21.05843575418999 -333.7317318435754)
POINT (21.57932960893859 -303.5198882681564)
POINT (21.57932960893859 -273.828938547486)
POINT (20.53754189944139 -236.8454748603352)
POINT (19.49575418994418 -206.1127374301676)
POINT (23.66290502793301 -172.775530726257)
POINT (25.74648044692742 -138.3965363128492)
POINT (27.30916201117323 -107.6637988826815)
POINT (25.22558659217881 -76.41016759776535)
POINT (27.30916201117323 -44.63564245810054)
```

### New

> I want to bring into the dictionary the identifier of the line id_line to which the point belongs

```
gdf = gpd.read_file("lines.shp")
for i,line in enumerate(df.geometry):
    for coord in line.coords:
        points = {"id":df.iloc[i].id, "pt":Point(coord)}
        print(points)
{'id': 0, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115007470>}
{'id': 0, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x1150565f8>}
{'id': 0, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115007470>}
{'id': 1, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x1150565f8>}
{'id': 1, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115007470>}
{'id': 1, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115056048>}
{'id': 1, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115007470>}
{'id': 2, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115056048>}
{'id': 2, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115007470>}
{'id': 2, 'pt': <shapely.geometry.point.Point object at 0x115056048>}
....
```

Comment: Thanks, in your answer a dictionary is created for each coordinate. What I am looking for is a single dictionary, where the value of the coordinates of each point will be appended to the corresponding key (id_line), like that: `{1 : [POINT Z(0,0,0), POINT Z(5,6,9), POINT Z(1,2,3)], 2 : [POINT Z(7,8,9), POINT Z(9,8,7), POINT Z(1,2,5)]}`

Comment: I have used your code to solve my problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You can get the coordinate tuples of a `LineString` via the `.coords` attribute. To convert the whole sequence of them into a numbered dictionary, you can use a dictionary expression like this:

```
>>> points = {
>>>     i: Point(coords)
>>>     for i, coords
>>>     in enumerate(line.coords)
>>> }

{0: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe8862f0c10>,
 1: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe886277070>,
 2: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe886277400>,
 3: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe8861ac130>,
 4: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe8861ac0a0>,
 5: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe886d64f70>,
 6: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe886c597c0>,
 7: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe88431dee0>,
 8: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe88431d370>,
 9: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe88431dd30>,
 10: <shapely.geometry.point.Point at 0x7fe88431d970>}
```

Comment: Thanks, but instead of enumerate the points, I want to bring into the dictionary the identifier of the line `id_line` to which the point belongs, am trying this but is not working:


`lines_segments = list(gdf['geometry'])
id_traject = list(gdf['id_line'])
for line in lines_segments:
    for coord in line.coords:
        points = dict(zip(id_traject,Point(coord)))
        print(points)`

Comment: Look New in my answer

Comment: Ah, I had missed that. Thanks for the nice answer @gene!